# Connect not working with StateLess component in Redux-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, redux, redux-thunk

I'm dispatching an action from some-other component , and store is getting updated with `svgArr` property, but though the following Stateless component `connect'ed` to the store , it ain't getting updated when store changes for `svgArr`.

Is it how it suppose to behave as it's a stateless component ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

```
const Layer = (props) => {
  console.log(props.svgArr);
  return (<div style = {
    {
      width: props.canvasWidth,
      height: props.canvasWidth
    }
  }
  className = {
    styles.imgLayer
  } > hi < /div>);
};

connect((state) => {
  return {
    svgArr: state.svgArr
  };
}, Layer);

export default Layer;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of your code

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

// this should probably not be a free variable
const styles = {imgLayer: '???'};

const _Layer = ({canvasWidth}) => (
  <div className={styles.imgLayer} 
       style={{
         width: canvasWidth,
         height: canvasWidth
       }}
       children="hi" />
);

const Layer = connect(
  state => ({
    svgArr: state.svgArr
  })
)(_Layer);

export default Layer;
```

Comment: ya sorry , I removed style layers imports here to make the code succinct .

Comment: Sorry in my case, const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
    return{
        authentication :state.authentication,
    }
  }

const Constants = (props)=> ({
    BASE_URL: props.authentication.baseurl
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Constants);

Can you tell me what should i do now?

Answer (score 22):

You seem to be exporting Layer instead of the connected version of the Layer component.

If you look at the redux documentation: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-dispatch-and-todos

It should be something like

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {svgArr: state.svgArr}
}
export default connect(mapSTateToProps)(Layer)
```

Comment: Awesome . I just figured that out . Was bout to update the answer. But saw you already figured that out . Thanks .

Answer (score 3):

If you want to connect the stateless function you should wrap it into
 the another const:

```
const Layer = (props) => {
  return (
   <div > 
   </div>
 );
};

export const ConnectedLayer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Layer);
```

Comment: why should we do so? Can we just `export default connect(...` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here use redux with functional component in react native

import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const variable = useSelector(state => state.user.variable)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also pass multiple state object with functional components.

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

const PartialReview = ({auth, productreview}) => (
    <div className="row">
        <h2>{auth.uInfo._ubase}<h2>
        <p>{productreview.review_description}
    </div>
);

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {auth: state.auth,productreview: state.productreview}
    };
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PartialReview)
```